# Creating Charts using VBA and Sub Routines

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am creating charts using data from a tabs called Team1-Team8. I am creating the charts for each team ok but I can't get the charts into each team tab called "Team a - Charts". Below is the code i have so far for just Team A.My Parameter sheet, Column B has the names of the tabs for the charts and Column A is the Team names. Any pointers would help.

```
Sub LooproutineCharts()

Dim TeamName As String
Dim TeamNameCharts As String

For i = 4 To 12

TeamName = Sheets("Parameter").Range("A" & i).Value 'identify the location

TeamNameCharts = Sheets("Parameter").Range("B" & i).Value 'identify the location

Call Charts(TeamName) ' Call subroutine

Call Charts(TeamNameCharts) ' Call subroutine

Next i

End Sub

Sub Charts(TeamName As String)

'Create a Line Chart for Healthy Start Docu'

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets(TeamName)

 With Sheets(TeamName)
    lastRow = .Range("U" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
With ws
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "Variable A"
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=.Range("S3:U" & lastRow)

ActiveSheet.Shapes("Variable A").Top = 20
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Variable A").Left = 20
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Variable A").Height = 300
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Variable A").Width = 700

ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Variable A" TeamName"



    End With
    End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: in your Charts Sub within the "with ws", you are referencing the activesheet, which may well be different from the ws, so as a first measure you could try to remove the activesheet reference, so it just reads ".Shapes.addChart.Select"

Comment: thanks for the reply. I get a read only property error on the line "Parent.Name = "Variable A""

Comment: You are also using it in the ChartTitle (though the syntax is off), but is the "Variable A" intended for use other than referencing the shape?

Comment: Variable A is just a reference for the name of the chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest updating the Charts Sub to make use of [Worksheet.ChartObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822178.aspx)

Using the ChartObject, you can set it and won't have to reference a shape by name. It would look like this:

```
Sub Charts(TeamName As String)
    'Create a Line Chart for Healthy Start Docu'
    Dim theChart As ChartObject
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets(TeamName)

    With ws
        lastRow = .Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set theChart = .ChartObjects.Add(Left:=20, Top:=20, Width:=700, Height:=300)
        With theChart.Chart
            .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
            .SeriesCollection.Add Source:=ws.Range("S3:U" & lastRow)
            '.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ws.Range("S2:U2") 'I have no idea where your xaxis is placed, or if it exist
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = TeamName
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

I've taken the liberty to assume that the chart title should match the TeamName argument. I've also made it ready for the xAxis, but I have no oidea if it is relevant, or where it is placed

Comment: That has placed the charts in to the correct tabs! thanks!

Comment: Why is the question -1?